# not sure if using right syntax with object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create a function that take an object and a key whose value is an array and returns the object only with the array values that are greater than ten at that key. Otherwise, it should just return empty arrays. I think this works, but I keep getting told it doesn't.

```
function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
    var greaterThan10 = [];
    if (!(key in obj)) {
        return greaterThan10;
    } else if (obj[key].length === 0) {
        return greaterThan10;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
            if ((obj[key][i]) > 10) {
                greaterThan10.push(obj[key][i]);
            }
        }
        obj[key] = greaterThan10
        return obj
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the inputs, expected output and the issue you seem to be seeing? Error, incorrect output? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Should the function return the object (with the `key` property changed) or the array? Yours does both, but in different cases, which is… suboptimal.

Comment: I agree with Bergi here. I think your issue may be a misunderstanding of the requirements. From what you describe in your writeup, this is "correct." The function sometimes returns an empty array, and it sometimes returns an object with a filtered array at the given key. I'm guessing that this is not the expected behavior from whoever gave you the original requirements.

Comment: weirdly, the instructions want both...they want an empty array sometimes and sometimes the object with the key property changed. I found that confusing too. I tried modifying it so it always return a modified object, but it's saying that it doesn't return a modified object at all.

Comment: wait, you were right...it just wanted an array each time...Thanks!